# Django javascript for dynamic html table cells

Tags: javascript, django

I'm attempting to access the contents of a cell, within my django template using javascript.

The table can contain x rows. When any of the "click to show" links (in the TEST column) are clicked, I would like the row's {{ i.description }} to be passed through to my views (ajax_test function), the "click to show" link to disappear and be replaced with the returned html from the view. I've included my terrible javascript attempt, knowing full well that this doesn't do what I'm asking. If anyone could help, it would be very much welcomed.

Template:

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if elements %}
<p>Found {{ elements|length }} Element{{ elements|pluralize }}.</p>
<div class="datagrid"><table>
    <thead><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Parameter Arguments</th>
    <th>TEST</th>
    <tbody>
    {% for i in elements %}
    <tr class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}alt{% else %}{% endif %}">
        <td><a href="/myapp/{{ i.id }}/editElement">{{ i.name }}</a></td>
        <td><div id="desc">{{ i.description }}</div></td>
        <td>{{ i.type }}</td>
        <td>{% for a in i.parameter.all %}{{ a.argument }}{% endfor %}</td>
        <td><div class="clicks"><a href="#">click to show</a></div></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table></div>
  {% endblock %}
```

Javascript (this is where I haven't got a clue really, the code below is a failed attempt). The code is included as a static file (ajax_test.js, which is loaded from base.html)

```
$(function(){   
   var myCell = document.getElementById("desc");
   var cellContents = (myCell.innerHTML);
    $('.clicks').click(function() {             
        $.ajax({     
            type: "POST",   
            url: "/myapp/test_ajax/", 
            data: {   
                'ajax_data' : cellContents, 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val() 
            },
            success: ajaxSuccess, 
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function ajaxSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
{
    $('.here').html(data); //I would like to put this in the "click to show" cell. I was placing it in a random div for testing.
}
```

test_ajax view:

```
def ajax_test(request):
    if request.POST:
        ajax_data = request.POST['ajax_data']
        ajax_query = #some generic lookup using ajax_data
    return render_to_response('myapp/ajax_test.html', {'ajax_query': ajax_query})
```

ajax_test template (to be returned to the cell):

```
{{ ajax_query }}
```

Comment: Did you forget to close out your `<thead>` and the `<tr>` within it?

Comment: I certainly did! Apologies, I've had to filter out a lot of the content from my original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

html

```
<td><div class="clicks"><a class="click-to-show" href="#" data-desc="{{ i.description }}">click to show</a></div></td>
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
   $('.click-to-show').click(function(e) {             
       $.ajax({     
           type: "POST",   
           url: "/myapp/test_ajax/", 
           data: {   
               'ajax_data' : $(e.target).attr("data-desc"), 
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val() 
           },
           success: function ajaxSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               $(e.target).parent().html(data);
           }, 
           dataType: 'html'
       });

   });

});
```

As you can see we keep the DOM relative to link element all the time, since we render rows multiple times, this will make sure we update the correct row.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get a HTTP POST from your suggestion. I've replaced the table's <td> with your HTML and replaced all my javascript with yours.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention to the browser console: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'

Comment: brilliant. I've been failing on this for many, many hours. You're a star!